# Eclipse double-click whitespace

Tags: eclipse, whitespace, pydev, double-click

In Eclipse Juno with PyDev,

Please let me know How to auto-select whitespace when I double-click a space.

In other editors, I can auto-select all whitespaces when I double-clicked a space between the spaces.
However, In Eclipse, it doesn't work.

for example,

```
         var          = 111
```

when I double click any space between 'r' and '=', all white space should be selected.

Many thanks in advance~

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're right, this is something that isn't working on PyDev/Eclipse.

Please create a feature request at

https://sw-brainwy.rhcloud.com/tracker/PyDev/

Note: the work is guided through votes in the tracker or pull requests, if someone is interested in doing a pull-request, the related class would be: org.python.pydev.editor.PyDoubleClickStrategy (and details for getting the pydev code: http://pydev.org/developers.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. As time goes by, I'm getting familiar with this "un-selected" features :0

Comment: This should be fixed for the next PyDev release (3.4)